# Ehcache not working with Spring boot application

Tags: spring, caching, spring-boot, ehcache, spring-cache

I have a Spring boot application where i am using ehcache. The Ehcache is working fine if i have only one entity class but if i have more than 1 entity class the ehcache is not working and i am getting the below error:-

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myapp.beans.Contact cannot be cast to com.myapp.beans.Department
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102.findOneById(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.myapp.service.impl.DepartmentServiceImpl.show(DepartmentServiceImpl.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
```

My Java Code :-

**DepartmentRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface DepartmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Department, Integer> {

    @Cacheable(value="appCache")
    @Query("select d from Department d where d.id=:id")
    Department findOneById(@Param("id") int id);
}
```

**ContactRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface ContactRepository extends JpaRepository<Contact, Integer> {

    @Cacheable(value = "appCache")
    @Query("select c from Contact c where c.id=:id")
    Contact findOneById(@Param("id") int id);

}
```

ehcache.xml

```
<ehcache>
    <cache name="appCache" maxBytesLocalHeap="50m" timeToLiveSeconds="100"></cache>
</ehcache>
```

The entire code is available at - https://github.com/iftekharkhan09/SpringCaching . Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have "key collisions", because your cache's names are identical.
I suggest to rename the caches, like this:

```
@Cacheable(value="appCache1")
    @Query("select d from Department d where d.id=:id")
    Department findOneById(@Param("id") int id);

@Cacheable(value = "appCache2")
    @Query("select c from Contact c where c.id=:id")
    Contact findOneById(@Param("id") int id);
```

Also you have to create each of these caches in ehcache.xml

Another way - use key in your cache, you can read about it [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache)